# C2DM Registration ID refresh issue handling

Tags: android, android-c2dm

When our "Registration ID" (given by the C2DM) refreshed, do we get a notification from the C2DM by asking us to register the device (which runs the C2DM enable application) again? 
OR
Do we have to code in the app to check it continuously from the C2DM server.

---

IF we are getting a new Registration ID from the C2DM server, will it come the same way when we first register the App? That means;

- to the java class where I have extends the BroadcastReceiver
- add uses-permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"

I visited this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4265514/833007) also. According to that, what will happen if our app is shutdown and the process is killed. [life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) Still they fire up the Intent we need to get new Registration ID or we are not getting any notification till we start the Activity again?

I have completed the app successfully. Only need to handle the "Registration ID" refreshed situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My exerience says that the registration ID does not expire when the process quits. If an app has registered with the C2DM and its process was terminated, C2DM messages are still delivered. The system quietly starts the app process and instantiates the broadcast receiver.

Comment: OK... thanks. I have completed the app and installed it to a TAB also. Still it is working and didn't get any issue after that. Thanks for the reply.